# C# MySQL Connection problems

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm trying to connect a C# application (using Visual C# 2008 Express Edition) to a remote MySQL server. I have the drivers for this, but when I followed the tutorials (including adding the pooling and connection reset properties), I get an error that: *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.* I've included the two lines of code that should be making a connection. The error is thrown on the second line.

```
        MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection("database=d*******;Data Source=mysql.netfirms.com;user id=*******;pwd=*****;pooling=false;connection reset=false");
        connect.Open();
```

Comment: tried using try..catch to get the exact error??

Comment: Could it be related to [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=33909) bug?

Comment: unlikely, as I downloaded the libraries yesterday, and based on the dates in that bug, the patch should be included in the current release.

Comment: Can you add the stack Trace to this? I think that would be helpful...

Comment: The issue was related to my server in the end. The datasource, while properly defined, could not be located, but it was not giving a sensible error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try setting the connection string outside of the constructor to help narrow down the issue:

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection();
//Do you get the null exception in this next line?
connect.ConnectionString = "your conn string here";
connect.Open(); //-> If you get the exception here then the problem is with the connection string and not the MySqlConnection constructor.
```

If you do get the exception in the connect.ConnectionString = ... line, then the problem is with the driver and sounds like you need to reinstall it.

I would also try a simpler connection string, without the pooling and reset keys.

Comment: I get the exception on the connect.Open(); line. I added the pooling and reset keys based on a response to someone with a similar problem, but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Can C# really return null from a constructor? In Java that's impossible. Either you get a valid object reference or an Exception is thrown.

Comment: No, but the constructor itself can reference a null object within its body, therefore throwing a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post more code? The exception line is probably a bit off due to compiler optimization or related. Constructors *must* return an object or throw an exception. It is impossible to say

```
MyType item = new MyType();
Debug.Fail(item == null); // will never fail.
```

The null reference is probably on the line just above your instantiation.